# Event listener, alert when jQuery is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I create an alert after jQuery is loaded and fully usable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to show you how to do what you want, and then tell you what I think about it:

```
(function checkJquery() {
  if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
    setTimeout(checkJquery, 500);
  }
  else {
    alert('jQuery is loaded.');
  }
})();
```

Normally when you're using jQuery, you would will include it in a `<script>` tag in your `<head>`. All such scripts are loaded in the order they are defined, so if you load it first, it will be available for all subsequent scripts. Therefore you should never need to check for it.

If you find yourself using a lot of javascript functionalities on your site, and want to make sure all your module dependencies are in check, I would suggest to check out [RequireJS](http://www.requirejs.org)

Comment: Polling should be discouraged when event listeners can do the same job.

Comment: In this case, what he's looking to do should be discouraged. Since jQuery does not fire an event when it gets loaded, polling is the only option. Presumably he's not loading jQuery in his initial markup otherwise it would be available on `window.onLoad`

Comment: You could still use the `load` event even if the `script` element were added later.

Comment: @alex, I am not sure we are talking about the same thing. Try the following code in your favourite environment, and the `load` event will not fire:

`document.addEventListener('load', function(e) {console.log(e);});
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
`

Comment: In that case, you'd have to attach the `load` event directly to that `script` element.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){
    alert("jQuery + DOM loaded.");
});
```

<sup>**(jQuery is immediately available after including it in `<script>`.)*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know when the `script` element containing jQuery has finished loading...

```
document.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    if (typeof jQuery == "function") {
        // jQuery is available.
    }
});
```

Attach this event listener before any of your `script` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Start using firebug if u havent. Its extremely useful. In the NET tab, you can see all the files being loaded, http requests, everything.

Answer (score 0):

The browser executes JS in the order that it finds it as it parses your document, including JS in external scripts. So jQuery will be loaded and "fully usable" immediately after the `<script>` element that includes it, and you can put an alert immediately after that `<script>` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
   if (jQuery)
      alert("jQuery is now loaded");
</script>
```

I've included the `if (jQuery)` part because if the path to jquery.js is incorrect or something else goes wrong to prevent the file loading then (obviously) jQuery wouldn't be available. But in normal circumstances that `if` test would be successful.

If you want to actually manipulate DOM elements on the page then you will need to include the script that does so *after* those elements, or in a jQuery document.ready handler, or in an onload handler:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       alert("jQuery is loaded, and the DOM is ready too.");
   });
</script>
```